# Adding events to NSWindow using Cocoa and Objective-C++

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, objective-c++

I've seen a lot of questions, but I couldn't find anything what helped me. I've looked at many Apple developer pages, but I find those to be a bit unclear.

I want to make applications in Objective-C++ without Xcode or any other IDE that does all the work for me. My IDE is Atom, and I compile with g++. I have the following class to create a window:

```
//Window.mm
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#import "Cocoa/Cocoa.h"

class Window
{
    private: NSWindow* window;

    public: Window(const char* title, int x, int y, int w, int h, NSColor* bg = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.3f green:0.3f blue:0.3f alpha:1.0f])
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        [NSApplication sharedApplication];

        NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(x, y, w, h);
        NSUInteger windowStyle = NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable;
        NSRect rect = [NSWindow contentRectForFrameRect:frame styleMask:windowStyle];

        this->window = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:rect styleMask:windowStyle backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO] autorelease];
        [this->window makeKeyAndOrderFront: this->window];
        [this->window setBackgroundColor: bg];
        [this->window setTitle: [NSString stringWithUTF8String:title]];
        [this->window orderFrontRegardless];

        [pool drain];
        [NSApp run];
  }
};
#endif
```

From what I did understand is that I need to do something with an NSView, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. How will I be able to get key input from my window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass NSWindow in order to receive key input events, for example:

KWCustomWindow.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface KWCustomWindow : NSWindow

@end
```

KWCustomWindow.m

```
#import "KWCustomWindow.h"

@implementation KWCustomWindow

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Key Down");
}

@end
```